# WatchKit: Speech to text conversion in WatchKit Apps

Tags: iphone, ios8, watchkit, siri

Can any one help me with a sample code for adding Speech to Text conversion  feature in Apple Watchkit apps.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/WKInterfaceCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html , see text input

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Here is the documentation: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions:allowedInputMode:completion:

The code look like this. You provide a suggestions array with words (or emoji too) and you set the allowed input mode that can accept animated emoji, emoji or plan text only.

```
[self presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions:@[@"hello", @"world"] allowedInputMode:WKTextInputModePlain completion:^(NSArray *results) {
    NSLog(@"results: %@", results);
}];
```

The result is this:

[image]

Comment: Do you know of anyway to simulate the dictation? I know the simulator does not support it, and apple watch isn't out there yet, anyway to test this?

Comment: You can't test it in Simulator and I doubt it will be available anytime soon. It'll probably require a real device to test it.

Answer (score 7):

You can ask for user input and give him suggestion (see Swift example bellow).

```
self.presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions(["suggestion 1", "suggestion 2"] allowedInputMode: .Plain, completion: { (answers) -> Void in
    if reply && reply.count > 0 {
        if let answer = answers[0] as? String {
            println("\answer")
        }
    }
})
```

If **suggestion** is **nil** it **goes directly to dictation**. It is not working on the simulator but it is on real watch.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions(["Y","N"], allowedInputMode: WKTextInputMode.Plain,
    completion:{(results) -> Void in
        let aResult = results?[0] as? String
        print(aResult)
})
```