# AppleWatch Speech-to-Text functionality not working

Tags: swift, speech-to-text, watchos-2

I am trying to implement Speech-to-text feature for watchkit app.
I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984678/watchkit-speech-to-text-conversion-in-watchkit-apps) question which has sample code.

Following is the code I tried:

```
self.presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions(["Start it", "Stop it"], allowedInputMode: .Plain, completion: { (selectedAnswers) -> Void in
    if selectedAnswers.count > 0 {
        if let spokenReply = selectedAnswers[0] as? String {
            self.label.setText("\(spokenReply)")
        }
    }
})
```

`label` is a label to display text I speak.
When I run it, it shows the screen where you are supposed to speak (Siri kind of screen) and you have two options on top: ‘Cancel', and ‘Done'. Once I am done speaking, I tap on ‘Done’ but screen doesn’t go away or shows me initial screen, I always have to tap on ‘Cancel’ to go back, and I don’t get any speech data in form of text. I checked it and seems like `selectedAnswers` is always an empty array, unless I tap on the "Start it"/"Stop it" options.

Can anyone help me with this? I want to show the spoken message on `label`. I have  code inside `awakeWithContext` method in InterfaceController.swift file, am I supposed to put it somewhere else?

I am using iPhone with iOS 9 beta 2 and watchOS 2 beta on AppleWatch.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask for user input and give him suggestion (see Swift example bellow).

```
self.presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions(["suggestion 1", "suggestion 2"] allowedInputMode: .Plain, completion: { (answers) -> Void in
if answers && answers.count > 0 {
    if let answer = answers[0] as? String {
        println("\answer")
    }
}
})
```

If suggestion is nil it goes directly to dictation. It is not working on the simulator but it is on real watch.

**Your approach is correct but something is wrong with your SIRI , try changing the language.**

It should work like these.

[image] [image] [image] [image]

Comment: So what is `reply` in your code? How do you get it and where should it be defined? (I thought it is supposed to be `answers` and not `reply`)

Comment: There was some problem with Siri on my iPhone because of which it wasn't converting speech to text, now it's working fine, thanks!

Comment: happy.to hear.that.!! enjoy coding :)